# Using Quantity[] units causes errors in my calculation

Tags: fitting, units

I have an interpolation function in which I wish to use actual units. If I perform the calculation normally, it works fine and returns a proper FittedModel.

To illustrate my problem, consider the following:

(*CALCULATION WITHOUT UNITS*)

```
xB = {0.00, 0.076, 0.164, 0.300, 0.479, 0.638, 0.854, 0.941, 1.00};
pP = {44.0, 42.2, 39.5, 36.4, 30.4, 27.6, 22.4, 12.9, 0.00};
pT = {44.0, 66.4, 84.0, 99.8, 105.8, 108.4, 109.0, 104.5, 94.4};
torrToPascal = 133.3223;
pPPascal = pP*torrToPascal;
pTPascal = pT*torrToPascal;
pBz = pTPascal - pPPascal;
nlmpBz = Transpose[{xB, pBz}];
nlmpPp = Transpose[{xB, pPPascal}];
linfit = NonlinearModelFit[nlmpBz, (x2)*pBz[[-1]]*Exp[a (1 - x2) + b (1 - x2)^2 + c (1 - x2)^3], {a, b, c}, x2]
```

This returns: `FittedModel[12585.6 E^(0.312901 (1-x2)+1.5389 (1-x2)^2-0.485642 (1-x2)^3) x2`

Now when I try to use `Quantity[]`, the following happens:

(*CALCULATION WITH UNITS*) (xB = fraction and thus dimensionless)

```
xB = {0.00, 0.076, 0.164, 0.300, 0.479, 0.638, 0.854, 0.941, 1.00};
pP = Quantity[{44.0, 42.2, 39.5, 36.4, 30.4, 27.6, 22.4, 12.9, 0.00}, 
   "Torr"];
pT = Quantity[{44.0, 66.4, 84.0, 99.8, 105.8, 108.4, 109.0, 104.5, 
    94.4}, "Torr"];
pPPascal = UnitConvert[pP, "Pascal"];
pTPascal = UnitConvert[pT, "Pascal"];
pBz = pTPascal - pPPascal; 
nlmpBz = Transpose[{xB, pBz}];
nlmpPp = Transpose[{xB, pPPascal}];
linfit = NonlinearModelFit[nlmpBz, (x2)*pBz[[-1]]*Exp[a (1 - x2) + b (1 - x2)^2 + c (1 - x2)^3], {a, b, c}, x2]
```

Now to me this seems like the exact same calculation, only with the proper units. Mathematica disagrees and yields the following result:

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrnq: The function value 0.5 ((0. Pa+2.71828^(3. Automatic) (0. Pa))^2+0. ((Pa)^2)+(-3226.4 Pa+2.71828^(2.56667 Automatic) (956.508 Pa))^2+(-5932.85 Pa+2.71828^(2.11917 Automatic) (2064.04 Pa))^2+(-8452.64 Pa+2.71828^(1.533 Automatic) (3775.69 Pa))^2+(-10052.5 Pa+2.71828^(0.933862 Automatic) (6028.52 Pa))^2+(-10772.4 Pa+2.71828^(0.540482 Automatic) (8029.63 Pa))^2+(-11545.7 Pa+2.71828^(0.170428 Automatic) (10748.1 Pa))^2+(-12212.3 Pa+2.71828^(0.0626864 Automatic) (11843.1 Pa))^2) is not a real number or quantity at {a,b,c} = {Automatic,Automatic,Automatic}. >>
```

What am I missing to resolve this issue? As always, your help is most appreciated.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` does not yet support `Quantity` units.

Comment: @ilian I suspected as much, but couldn't find confirmation anywhere in the docs, apart from the evidence brought by the OP. Would you have a resource listing functions that do / do not support `Quantity`?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Are there also issues with Solve that you happen to know of? Because I'm experiencing various errors there as well.

Comment: @MarcoB I think it would be good to have such a list. The closest thing is [Units Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnitsOverview.html) which covers the initial scope as of version 9 and mentions various symbolic, numerical and statistical functions. Then the [New in V10](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/) pages mention some more recent extensions to visualization functions, `Interpolation` etc. The latest numerical function to become aware of quantities is `NIntegrate` and it is likely unit support will continue to be added throughout the system.

Comment: @user27448 I would be interested in any examples of `Solve` failing where it shouldn't. Please feel free to post them on the site and/or email them to `support@wolfram.com`.